# ColdFusion & MSSQL : how to insert multiple rows with one unique id in one submission

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

can anyone help me on how to submit multiple rows in one submission?

this survey form will display a set of skill that derived from table skill.
the teacher will have to check the students skill's in checkboxes and click submit.

a student can have more than one skill. 
if he has 3 skills, then the data that is sent into database will be in 3 rows once the teacher click the submit button. (table studentskill)

```
<cfoutput query="skill">
<tr>
    <td>#skill.skillname#</td>
    <td align="center">:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="skillid" value="skillid" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
```

**table skill**

```
+---------+------------+
| skillid | skillname  |

+---------+------------+

| 1       | draw       |

+---------+------------+

| 2       | read       |

+---------+------------+

| 3       | dance      |

+---------+------------+
```

**table studentskill**

```
+----------+----------|

|studentid | skillid  |

+----------+----------+
| 001      | 1        |
| 001      | 2        |
| 002      | 1        |
| 002      | 2        |
| 002      | 3        |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This is a simple question that is presented very well. Gear job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple approach for inserting multiple records is an `INSERT .. SELECT`. (It is also mentioned in the link banyr posted). Because the skill id's are stored in another table, you can use an `IN` clause to `SELECT` them. Then insert those values directly into your other table `studenSkill` with a simple query, no looping.

```
INSERT INTO studenSkill ( studenId, skillId )
SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
       , skillId
FROM   skill
WHERE  skillId IN 
       (
       <cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">
       )
```

> ```
>     <input type="checkbox" name="skillid" value="skillid" checked="checked">
> ```

BTW, in case that is not a typo, do not forget the # signs around the query column name ie "skillid"

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="skillid" value="#skillid#" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the following syntax, assuming you're on SQL server 2008:

```
INSERT INTO StudentSkill (StudentID, SkillID)
VALUES (100, 1), (100, 2), (100, 3)
```

This method gleaned from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/), which also contains a couple of alternative methods.

You'll just need to iterate over the list of IDs in FORM.skillid (assuming that's how your form works) to build up the SQL  above. Also, make sure you use `<CFQueryParam>` on the values when you build up the SQL. Something like the code below ought to do:

```
<cfif ListLen(FORM.skillid)>
  <cfquery>
   INSERT INTO StudentSkill (StudentID, SkillID)
    VALUES
   <cfloop list="#form.skillid#" index="skill">
     (<cfqueryparam value="#form.studentID#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, 
       <cfqueryparam value="#skill#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">)
   </cfloop>
  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: That looks great! That's much easier than I have done it in the past.

Comment: You said that syntax would work with sql server and I'll take your word for it.  It probably won't work with other db software.  The OP, @vamps, might want to take note of that.  Kudos for having the loop inside the query instead of the other way around.

Comment: MySQL supports same syntax as well. @barnyr - I edited your code to ensure multiple value sets are separated by commas

Comment: @DanBracuk - my edits must be accepted by barnyr before they are visible in his answer.

Comment: @azawaza - For some reason your edits got rejected by others before I got a chance to review them. Props to you though for spotting the missing commas in the code i posted. I'll fix the example up shortly